# Java: Creating a class recognized somewhere else in the file

Tags: java, class, collections, compiler-errors

In ClassA.java I have

```
class User {
    private int id;
    private String nick;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int i) {
        id = i;
    }
    public String getNick() {
        return nick;
    }
    public void setNick(String n) {
        nick = n;
    }
}

public final class ClassA {
    private List<User> = new LinkedList();
    public Collection<String> getUsers() {
        LinkedList out = new LinkedList();
        Iterator loop = out.iterator();
        while (loop.hasNext()) {
            User u = loop.next();
            out.add(u.getNick());
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

When I compile this, I get an error telling me that on the line containing

```
User u = loop.next();
```

It tells me that `u` cannot be cast to a `User`.  Is there something further I should do to indicate to the compiler the static type of `u`?

Comment: `private List<User> = new LinkedList();` does not compile. And you are using raw values instead of generics for your `out` and `loop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinkedList` (or `List` in general) is a generic type. Without specifying the generic argument, by default it would be interpreted as being an `Object`. You need to specify your list accordingly:

```
List<User> out = new LinkedList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use generics:

```
List<User> out = new LinkedList<>();
Iterator<User> loop = out.iterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a constructor to the class User

```
User(){}
```

and here

```
private List<User> test = new LinkedList();
```

a name